# Python requests headers can I use a 2d dictionary?

Tags: python, rest, https, python-requests

I need to format the following as a header for the requests library and I dont know how I would do it

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization:
        OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key",
        oauth_nonce="random_string_or_timestamp",
        oauth_signature="your_consumer_secret&",
        oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
        oauth_timestamp="current_timestamp",
        oauth_callback="your_callback"
User-Agent: some_user_agent
```

I was thinking of making it a 2d dictionary but trying that in requests just gives me an error saying that the second level should be a string and not a dict.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `Authorization` header to one line. For example:

```py
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="your_consumer_key",oauth_nonce="random_string_or_timestamp",oauth_signature="your_consumer_secret&",oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_timestamp="current_timestamp",oauth_callback="your_callback"',
    "User-Agent": "some_user_agent",
}

url = "https://httpbin.org/get"

print(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text)
```